# MySQL Query is missing rows

Tags: mysql, sql

So I need a little bit of help. I cannot seem to find the correct JOIN or whatever it is that I need in order to get all of the results that I am looking for.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(hd.value) as total_rows,
    ROUND(AVG(hd.value), 2) as OEE_AVG,
    dl.line_id,
    hd.shift,
    ol.description
FROM
    dashboard_to_dashboard_lines ddl
JOIN dashboard_lines dl ON dl.id = ddl.dashboard_line_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN operation_lines ol ON (dl.line_id = ol.line_id)
JOIN historical_data hd ON dl.gauge_tag_id = hd.tag_id
WHERE
    hd.timestamp BETWEEN '2016-01-04 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-04 23:59:59'
    AND ddl.dashboard_id = 1
    AND hd.value < 200
GROUP BY
    dl.line_id,
    hd.shift
ORDER BY
    hd.shift,
    dl.line_id ASC
```

The desired result would look like:

```
________________________________________________________
| total rows | oee_avg | line_id | shift | description |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| 858        | 80.24   |  1      |  1    | Line Desc   |
| 432        | 60.21   |  2      |  1    | Line Desc   |
| 234        | 70.75   |  3      |  1    | Line Desc   |
| 865        | 10.45   |  1      |  2    | Line Desc   |
| 864        | 20.26   |  2      |  2    | Line Desc   |
| 823        | 30.44   |  3      |  2    | Line Desc   |
| 423        | 56.14   |  1      |  3    | Line Desc   |
| 234        | 12.74   |  2      |  3    | Line Desc   |
| 534        | 43.64   |  3      |  3    | Line Desc   |
```

Basically, I get the avg for the values for each line associated with a dashboard separated by shift.

I primarily get the data that I need with the exception of 1 line, on 1 shift for the provided time frame. (other time frames provide the desired results with all lines across all shifts). So I am assuming that there is no data there for the calculation which leads to the row being left out.

I tried doing an outer join (mixed and matched across the query) without any luck.

I know it is hard without an SQL fiddle, but I was hoping someone might have some insight that would assist me.

Thanks in advance.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/477a7)

Edit: Added SQL Fiddle link

Comment: Your table schema would be helpful here.

Comment: Added link to SQL fiddle with the schema for those tables

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data I can't test, but this should point you in the right direction if it doesn't work completely. The important part is that you need a source for all of the possible combinations of line/shift that are possible. In this case I've used a subquery against your tables without limiting by dates, etc., but you might have a better way of getting those. Also, in similar cases the data might not exist at all for some values where you still want to see things on a report. For example, if I'm reporting on sales by day and a store was closed on Sunday but I still want to see zeroes for that day. In a case like that you need to create the values some other way besides selecting from your existing table(s).

```
SELECT
    COUNT(hd2.value) AS total_rows,
    ROUND(AVG(hd.value), 2) AS OEE_AVG,
    SQ.line_id,
    SQ.shift,
    OL.description
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT dl.line_id, hd.shift
        FROM dashboard_lines dl
        INNER JOIN historical_data hd ON hd.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id
    ) SQ
INNER JOIN dashboard_to_dashboard_lines ddl ON ddl.dashboard_id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dashboard_lines dl2 ON
    dl2.id = ddl.dashboard_line_id AND
    dl2.line_id = SQ.line_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN historical_data hd2 ON
    hd2.tag_id = dl.gauge_tag_id AND
    hd2.shift = SQ.shift AND
    hd2.timestamp BETWEEN '2016-01-04 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-04 23:59:59' AND
    hd2.value < 200
LEFT OUTER JOIN operation_lines ol ON ol.line_id = dl2.line_id
GROUP BY
    SQ.line_id,
    SQ.shift
ORDER BY
    SQ.shift,
    SQ.line_id ASC
```

Also, please note that your check of the timestamp column could cause erroneous results if MySQL were to keep an accuracy beyond the second. Better to use `hd2.timestamp >= '2016-01-04 00:00:00' AND hd2.timestamp < '2016-01-05 00:00:00'`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will take your response and see what I can do

Comment: How would I go about creating the data that isn't there? (With a few subtle changes of table references the query ran just fine) -- It produces the exact results that mine does (lacking the one line that doesn't have the data). If it returned an empty result that would be fine so long as it had the line_id. -- Give me a few minutes and I will try to get you a fiddle that has data

Comment: Couldn't edit my above comment but after a couple attempts, the limit is too small on sqlfiddle for me to provide any type of "working" data for testing.

Comment: How you get the data that "isn't there" is up to you. In your case, since the data is only missing for certain time periods you'll see that the subquery that I used doesn't filter on the date. If you had look up tables for lines/shifts then you could use those. The key is that you want to start with that resultset and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to it with the other tables. Also, I see my mistake - putting some of the criteria in the `WHERE` clause instead of the `JOIN` clause. I'll correct that and hopefully the above will work.

Comment: I just made it back into work this morning as I had the afternoon tied up. I am going to get back into trying to solve this. I do truly appreciate your time in assisting me with this matter. I'll get back if I can learn anything further